# Where File converted Manually?

Tags: image-manipulation, www, file-conversion

I used many Sites on internet to Convert my Files online but they does not give the better quality they paste the images on it. Now I want to that the sites are convert it manually for better result. Is their any site who convert the document manually?

Comment: PARSE ERROR. What are you trying to say?

Comment: and WTF has this to do with C++?

Comment: Improvement to your questions to get better & more answers: What type of files are you trying to convert? What is the target format? Are you trying to avoid making them worse than the original or better? When you say manually, what sort of control are you after (eg brightness, sharpness)?

Comment: O_o how did this get an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

Just load your image into Photoshop, Gimp, Paint.net or whatever program you want to use, change the size of the image and save.